# SqlServer Object Explorer does not show stored procedures found in solution explorer --> Why?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio database project that I created by importing a production database.  So I have a lot of tables and stored procedures.   I am confused by one point....In the solutions Explorer I see all of the Stored Procedures, tables, etc...

But in the Solutions explorer on the local\DB ... I see the instance (etracs2013) ...but when I open up the tables and stored procedures there is nothing there ... I am sure this was the way it is supposed to work, but why is it doing this? and can I display my sandbox database from the solution explorer with all of the stored procedures.

Solution Explorer:
[image: Solution Explorer:]

Sql Server Object Explorer:
[image: Sql Server Object Explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items you see in Solution Explorer are files, that allow you to create the procedures.

To create them in your database, you need to run the files.

(Alternatively, it may be that your user account doesn't have permission to see the procedures in question, but it seems unlikely in this instance)

Comment: When I create a database project it created the empty database... then I populated the project using an import ... This created the schema and the stored procedures as sql....

Comment: So how do I get the local database to be populated with the store procedures and schema....???? I tried to start and run a stored procedure and of course it failed.... How do I populate the schema ??   Thanks... I think you have address the original question ...

Comment: ok... I had a bunch of warnings when I built the database, but I ASSUMED that the build process succeeded... (I choose to ignore the warning messages)...But it turns out the build process failed ... hence the reason I did not see the database in the sql server explorer...